# Insert newline after each line with a search pattern depending on the line before it

Tags: regular-expression, search, global-command

Basically, how can I add log statements like this with Vim?

Initial document (pseudocode):

```
   case VALUE_1:
       doFunc1();
   case VALUE_2:
       doFunc2();
       doAnotherFunc();
   case VALUE_THREE:
       doFunc3();
```

What I want to get:

```
   case VALUE_1:
       print("processing value: VALUE_1");
       doFunc1();
   case VALUE_2:
       print("processing value: VALUE_2");
       doFunc2();
       doAnotherFunc();
   case VALUE_THREE:
       print("processing value: VALUE_THREE");
       doFunc3();
```

Comment: I'd just type it, possibly copying and pasting the variable names. Your title indicates you already prepared some kind of `:substitute` command. Please [edit] and share.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Friedrich @romani well, I know how to insert new line after a search pattern with a global command using `g/serach/normal! oMy text` but that's the same text on every line, here I need different text, depending on the line I'm inserting after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
:%s/\vcase (\S*):/\0\r       print("processing value: \1");/
```

Or to deal better with the various indentation:

```
:%s/\v^(\s*)case (\S*):/\0\r\1    print("processing value: \2");/
```

Or as suggested by @Friedrich:

```
:%s/\vcase (\S*):/\0\rprint("processing value: \1");/
```

and ask Vim to reindent the code using the `=` operator.

Comment: The leading whitespace is likely to be off in the general case. Better omit it and indent using `==`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you both

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in your example you only need *one* print statement to leverage the full variable substitution power of the pseudocode interpreter to do your work

```
print("processing value: ", foo)
switch (foo)
    case VALUE_1:
        doFunc1();
    ...
```

This will work unless switch-case is broken, in which case you have a much bigger problem.

Let's assume we want to add a print to each case, anyway. I'd move my cursor on `VALUE_1` and then

```
yawoprint("processing value: <C-R>0");<Esc>
```

You could turn the line above into a mapping or a macro if you wanted. I don't, so I won't.

Anyway, it will make your code look like this

```
    case VALUE_1:
        print("processing value: VALUE_1");
        doFunc1();
    case VALUE_2:
        doFunc2();
        doAnotherFunc();
    case VALUE_THREE:
        doFunc3();
```

In fact, *I would not repeat* but yank the line I just wrote using `yy`, search to the next case with `/case`, put the line and increment the 1 using <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>.

```
    case VALUE_1:
        print("processing value: VALUE_1");
        doFunc1();
    case VALUE_2:
        print("processing value: VALUE_2");
        doFunc2();
        doAnotherFunc();
    case VALUE_THREE:
        doFunc3();
```

For the final print, I can just repeat the last search with `n`, `p` again, jump to the 1 with `f1` (that's f and 1, not <kbd>F1</kbd>) and change it using `cwTHREE<Esc>`

```
    case VALUE_1:
        print("processing value: VALUE_1");
        doFunc1();
    case VALUE_2:
        print("processing value: VALUE_2");
        doFunc2();
        doAnotherFunc();
    case VALUE_THREE:
        print("processing value: VALUE_THREE");
        doFunc3();
```

Done. And we didn't even have to concern ourselves with the arcane knowledge that is regex.